# Convert YV12 to NV21 (YUV YCrCb 4:2:0)

Tags: java, c#, image-processing, yuv, image-formats

How can you convert:

***YV12***   (FOOURCC code: 0x32315659)
to
***NV21***   (FOURCC code: 0x3132564E)
(YCrCb 4:2:0 Planar)

These are both common formats for Android video handling, but there is no example online converting directly between the two. You can go through RGB but I assume that will be too inefficient.

Ideally in **C#** or **Java**, but can convert code from whatever else...

The input is a **byte[]**, and the width and height are known.

I have been trying to follow the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion) but cannot get it to function cleanly.

*For the bounty: a function taking the byte[] and outputting a byte[] in the other format.*

Comment: From this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538197(v=vs.85).aspx I'm going down the line that I have to keep the Y samples, and move the Cr and Cb samples from being one after the other, to interleaved with Cr then Cb samples repeating?...

Comment: Or find code for going from YV12 to NV12, and then NV12 to NV21..

Comment: Try using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) (you can use `ffmpeg` result as reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my take on it. This is still untested but here it goes:

**YV12**
8 bit Y plane followed by 8 bit 2x2 subsampled V and U planes. So a single frame will have a full size Y plane followed 1/4th size V and U planes.

**NV21**
8-bit Y plane followed by an interleaved V/U plane with 2x2 subsampling. So a single frame will have a full size Y plane followed V and U in a 8 bit by bit blocks.

So here goes the code

```
public static byte[] YV12toNV21(final byte[] input,
                                final byte[] output, final int width, final int height) {

    final int size = width * height;
    final int quarter = size / 4;
    final int vPosition = size; // This is where V starts
    final int uPosition = size + quarter; // This is where U starts

    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, size); // Y is same

    for (int i = 0; i < quarter; i++) {
        output[size + i*2 ] = input[vPosition + i]; // For NV21, V first
        output[size + i*2 + 1] = input[uPosition + i]; // For Nv21, U second
    }
    return output;
}
```